# Error npm run prod on sass file (SassError: Undefined variable: "$gradient-colors".)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, sass-loader

i edit a ready make laravel VUE 2 project when i npm run prod it show this error:

`

```
ERROR in ./resources/src/assets/styles/sass/globals/_globals.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable: "$gradient-colors".
        on line 1 of resources/src/assets/styles/sass/globals/_palette.scss
        from line 5 of C:\xampp\htdocs\sas\resources\src\assets\styles\sass\globals\_globals.scss
>> @each $gcolor_name, $gcolor in $gradient-colors {
```

`

My _palette.scss file i got error on it:
`

```
@each $gcolor_name, $gcolor in $gradient-colors {
  $start-color: map-get($gcolor, start-color);
  $end-color: map-get($gcolor, end-color);

  .sidebar-#{$gcolor_name} {
    .sidebar-left {
      @include directional-gradient(-154deg, $start-color, $end-color);
    }
  }
  .#{$gcolor_name} {
    @include directional-gradient(-154deg, $start-color, $end-color);
  }
  .btn.#{$gcolor_name} {
    &:active,
    &.active {
      @include directional-gradient(-90deg, $start-color, $end-color);
    }
  }
}
```

`

How can i fix this???

i got this problem when i want run npm rum prod on laravel vue js 2 project

Comment: You are using this `$gradient-colors` variable, and apparently, it isn't there.

Comment: Yes this is .scss file